# Markup for postal addresses

Tags: html, semantic-markup, street-address, vocabulary

Which HTML5 markup should we use for postal addresses? And which vocabulary could we use for enabling machine-readability?

As an example, the address of [W3C’s main office](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/contact-mit):

> W3C/MIT
>   32 Vassar Street
>   Room 32-G515
>   Cambridge, MA 02139 USA

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [`address` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/sections.html#the-address-element) must only be used if this postal address represents the contact information for "its nearest `article` or `body` element ancestor", which, of course, is not the case for all addresses. But if `address` is used or not, it doesn’t affect the following.

The **whole address** should be enclosed in a [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), [because](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/dom.html#paragraph) "an address is also a paragraph".
As addresses should not be translated, the [`translate` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/dom.html#the-translate-attribute) should be set to `no`.

Each **line** (except the last one) should be followed by a [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element), because the line breaks are meaningful (or "part of the content", as the HTML5 spec calls it) in addresses.

Each **address part** (name, street, city, etc.) can be enclosed in a [`span` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). This is not required, but allows the use of semantic annotations.
Abbreviated address parts can be expanded with the [`abbr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/text-level-semantics.html#the-abbr-element), which can be useful for users not familiar with the address format (e.g., "What means *MA*?").

So up to this point, we have:

```
<p translate="no">
  W3C/MIT<br>
  32 Vassar Street<br>
  Room 32-G515<br>
  Cambridge, <abbr title="Massachusetts">MA</abbr> 02139 USA
</p>
```

#### Vocabularies

Schema.org’s [`PostalAddress` type](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) can be used for all address parts except for the room.

The [vCard Ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/) (which maps [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) to RDF) defines an [`Address` class](http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/#d4e1292). There doesn’t seem to be a way to specify the room.

Another [`Address` class](http://www.w3.org/ns/locn#locn:Address) is defined in the [ISA Programme Location Core Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/ns/locn). The room can be specified with the [`locatorName` property](http://www.w3.org/ns/locn#locn:locatorName).

Microformats has [`h-card`](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card) (with its `p-adr`) and [`h-adr`](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-adr). The room can be specified with `p-extended-address`.

Using the schema.org vocabulary with RDFa (Lite) as an example:

```
<p translate="no" typeof="schema:PostalAddress">
  <span property="schema:name">W3C/MIT</span><br>
  <span property="schema:streetAddress">32 Vassar Street</span><br>
  Room 32-G515<br>
  <span property="schema:addressLocality">Cambridge</span>, <abbr title="Massachusetts" property="schema:addressRegion">MA</abbr> <span property="schema:postalCode">02139</span> <abbr property="schema:addressCountry">USA</abbr>
</p>
```

Comment: This [microdatagenerator](http://www.microdatagenerator.com/local-business-schema) helped me to archive the above easily.