# Bootstrap <address> tag and itemscope itemtype

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup, microdata

My goal is showing a postal address in a web page using bootstrap. Including Microdata.

The basic option I was considering is

```
<div itemscope itemtype="schema.org/PostalAddress">
   <span itemprop="name">COMPANY NAME</span>
   <span itemprop="streetAddress">xxx</span>
   <!-- more itemprop here -->
</div>
```

...but regarding that HTML5/Bootstrap provides the `<address>` tag, I wonder if the following would be correct:

```
<address itemscope itemtype="schema.org/PostalAddress">
   <span itemprop="name">COMPANY NAME</span>
   <span itemprop="streetAddress">xxx</span>
   <!-- more itemprop here -->
</address>
```

Does using `<address>` instead of `<div>` gives any extra feature (for search engines, SEO, others...)?

What's the best way of doing so?

Edited: In this case the address refers the contact information for the author/owner of the page.

Comment: Tip: The <address> tag should NOT be used to describe a postal address, unless it is a part of the contact information. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp)

Comment: @AdamJeffers: Right. In this case the address refers to the contact information for the author/owner of the page.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML markup and Microdata markup are two separate worlds.

**Microdata parsers** don’t care if `div` or `address` is used, they have to handle them the same. You only have to make sure to [use an element that produces the value type you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669) (i.e., it’s easy for *item*, but there are differences for *string* vs. *datetime* vs. *absolute URL*).

**HTML parsers** care about the HTML elements you use, but not about your Microdata markup. Using [`address`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-address-element) instead of `div` conveys that the content of that element represents contact information (for the nearest `article` or `body`). What to make of this information is up to the consumer (search engines, accessibility tools, browser add-ons, etc.).

(And of course there might be consumers that take both, the HTML and the Microdata, into account, and deduce some clever things.)

The *best* way? First get your HTML right (use the most specific elements that are appropriate for your purpose) and then add Microdata attributes to your markup (and, if needed for that, add `div`/`span` elements).

See my answer [Markup for postal addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669) for the process (it uses RDFa instead of Microdata, but the idea is the same).