# Representing a place in Schema.org

Tags: location, schema.org

I am trying to understand how to identify a place in Schema.org. For example how to describe a [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) that is in Greenwich Village, New York.

I would expect to use the [`containedInPlace`](https://schema.org/containedInPlace) property and define a [`Place`](https://schema.org/Place) entity representing Greenwich Village.

There are two possibilities that I can see, either user the [`geo`](http://schema.org/geo)  property, or the [`globalLocationNumber`](https://schema.org/globalLocationNumber).

`geo` is not always viable, given that we don't have [`GeoShape`](http://schema.org/GeoShape) data for all locations, and [`GeoCoordinates`[7](http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates) doesn't really capture the concept of the business being in Greenwich Village.

I haven't looked much into `globalLocationNumber` much, but wonder what happens where the location in question doesn't have a [global location number](http://www.gs1.org/gln).

Any better suggestions?

Comment: It might depend on your exact use case. In case of the location of a business, what’s wrong with [`address`](http://schema.org/address)?

Comment: I think thats probably the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give the location of a [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), a straightforward way is to provide its address with the [**`address`**](http://schema.org/address) property.

Ideally with a [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) value ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669)), but if you don’t have the address in a structured format, you can provide a `Text` value instead.

Other general options include [`location`](http://schema.org/location) (e.g., if you can’t provide an address, but only the country or city), [`containedInPlace`](http://schema.org/containedInPlace) (e.g., if the business is located in another, well known place), and [`geo`](http://schema.org/geo) (e.g., if the place doesn’t have an address).