# Proper HTML footer address format?

Tags: html, footer, schema.org, semantic-markup, microdata

Is that proper HTML address format?

```
<div class="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Florist">
   <h5 class="">xxx</h5>

<div class="">  
  <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">xxx</span> 
        <span itemprop="postalCode">xxx</span> 
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">xxx</span>
  </span>   
</div>  

<div class="">
    <span>Phone: </span><a style="" href="tel:+xxxxxxxx" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="telephone">+xxxxxxxx</span></a></br>
    <span>Email: </span><a href="mailto:info@xxx.cz" itemprop="email">info@xxx.cz</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Or `<p>` and `<address>` schould be included, if yes, where is right place, to use them?

Comment: [Markup for postal addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26188003/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using schema.org Schemas you don't have to worry about the HTML tags you use. Only worry about tag parent->child structure so that the parent defines the item scope and the children define the itemprops. Finally use [Google's Structured Data test tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to verify your implementation.

Comment: Im using Schemas because of Google, but I live in Czech Republic, we have 50% of web taffic from Seznam (local web search engine) instead of Google, Im afraid  that Schema.org is not supported by Seznam. So I need an "safe" solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with marking up the address? If google shall understand the content as an address you are safe. Other crawlers who have not implemented schema.org will ignore it as they are simple HTML Tag attributes. I don't know how seznam has implemented address recognition on websites. Please have a look at their FAQ...

Comment: Im trying to not mess up Local SEO by wrong HTML. Seznam does not have such information in their FAQ. So safe is include <p> tags? If yes should I change <span> to <p> or surround by <p> an specific parts?

Comment: From general SEO point-of-view it's should be unimportant if you use <div> or <p>. You can also keep the <span> in your block elements. Just stick to your CSS structure so you don't have to add extra styling code. Other stuff I just found: http://refreshperspective.com/blog/article/is_the_html_address_tag_useful_for_seo/